# What does the phrase "whizzes by in a giddy blur" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases, phrasal-verbs

Could you please help me understand the meaning of the phrase "whizzes by in a giddy blur" in the following text (not available online) from the description of the game "Retro Bowl":

> Controlling your team’s offensive plays with passes, deft sidesteps,
>   and carefully timed drives for the line, the gameplay **whizzes by in a
>   giddy blur** – particularly when the opposition are in possession, their
>   actions described by a text commentary.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Whizzes by**" means "moves quickly past". With regard to an event, it refers to the passage of time. The writer is saying that the gameplay moves quickly.

"**Blur**", when used *literally*, describes an image that is indistinct or unclear. In many cases, it refers specifically to *motion blur*, which is when something is unclear due to it moving quickly (for example, a photograph taken from a moving vehicle using a slow shutter speed). However, we often use the word in a broader, *figurative* sense to describe something that moved so quickly it was difficult to take it all in - not necessarily visually, but mentally. That is the meaning implied in your example. As it refers to *gameplay* and not visuals, I do not believe it is suggesting that it was visually blurred. Rather, it suggests that a lot happens and you must concentrate to keep up.

"**Giddy**" has a number of meanings, but I think the most apt here is "disorientating and alarming, but exciting". This word adds excitement to the description of the gameplay, and confirms that the word 'blur' is mean in a *positive* way.

To sum up, "gameplay whizzes by in a giddy blur" means that the gameplay **moves quickly** and is **exciting**.